# edit multiple wordpress posts body text at the same time

Tags: wordpress, posts, editing

I am the owner of a WordPress books library website. I want to edit 23000 posts and add some text or replace some text or links from the body of the posts. I am unable to find any solution for quick editing. Because it will take me ages to complete this daunting task.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_content =  $wpdb->get_results("select post_content from wp_posts where ID = 9969");
  $content = $post_content[0]->post_content ;

  $replaced_content = preg_replace_callback('/code to replace in form of regex/',
       'code with which you want to replace',
        $content); 

$wpdb->query('UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = "'.$wpdb->_real_escape($replaced_content).'" WHERE ID = "'.$post_id.'"');
```

Comment: Greetings, It is really nice to see your response. I want to add text material to all posts. Some material will remain the same but some material has to change in each post like the name of the book, name of the author, download link and read online link. In fact, I want to add 3-4 paragraphs with headings, and links and a table to each and every post physically. I mean when google bot checks the posts material should be present in each and every post.